# Documentation on creating a Breeze.js DataAdapter

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to get Breeze.js talking to sharepoint. Does anyone know of any documentation on how to create a custom Breeze.js DataAdapter?

Comment: what did you find when you searched?

Comment: The Breeze ESPN Sample I made - http://www.breezejs.com/samples/espn - shows it, as does the Edmunds sample - http://www.breezejs.com/samples/edmunds

Comment: Thanks, that ESPN Sample looks interesting. I was looking more for a spec type document that explains what a custom dataatapter needs to implemnt.

Answer (score 1):

We are hoping to have some more guidance and documentation regarding connecting Breeze with Sharepoint endpoints within the next month or so.  This work is currently in progress. So please stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks Jay, Looking forward to it. Let me know if i an help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have breeze talk to sharepoint via oData.  You need datajs to add oData support to breeze and note the call to `breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });`.  See below.

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/q.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/datajs-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/breeze.debug.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/koGrid-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var my = {}; //my namespace
$(function () {
    var serverAddress = "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/";
    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serverAddress);


    my.vm = {
        customers: ko.observableArray([]),
        load: function () {
            var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("YourSPListHere").take(15);
            manager.executeQuery(query, function (data) {
                var results = data.results;
                my.vm.customers(results);
            });
        }
    }  
    my.vm.load();
    ko.applyBindings(my.vm);              
});      
</script>
```